# iTerm2 jumping to a folder bookmark

Tags: iterm, bookmarks

I need a simple bookmark just to cd to a folder.
I add a bookmark, select login shell and my desired directory.
When I use that bookmark my status gets changed from `host:folder user$` to `bash-3.2$` which is annoying.
Why does this happen?

Comment: iTerm2 is a alpha release so I would ask on their forums or bug tracker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possible solutions:

1. Set your bookmark's command to:

   login -fpl *USERNAME* /bin/bash --login

(replace *USERNAME* with your username)

2. Put this in your ~/.bashrc:

   source /etc/profile

Comment: This is what I've put in my ~/.bashrc: source /etc/profile;
source ~/.profile